# React - render prop, iterate over array does not show value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have to files, App.js and Example.js

App.js

```
import React from 'react'
import Example from './Example'

const App = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Example render={ students =>  <ul> Hi , {students.forEach( student => {return <div>{student}</div>}) } </ul>   } />
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

and Example.js

```
import React from 'react'

function Example(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            {props.render(["Maria", "Alice", "Gina", "Cleopatra"])}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Example
```

The expected result was ,,Hi Maria , Alice ..." i wanted to see the names, but for some reason, without no error, i only get ,,Hi"

Does anyone see the issue?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

I do not think you should use render props in this case. Also, the method you should use is `map`, because forEach does not return anything, it simply invokes function on the elements inside the array. Simply pass the students array to Example component and render them inside Example itself. Ex:

```
<Example  students={//studentsArray} />
```

then inside Example:

```
function Example(props) {
    return (
        <div>
            {props.students.map(student => <div>hi {student}</div>)}
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Indeed, you where right, when i switched map with forEach, it displayed the values. Many thanks @wyfy !

Comment: My reputation is still less then 15, so my vote is not shown, but as soon as i will pass 15, i will come back and vote every answer that helped me!

Answer (score 0):

Try using students.map() instead of forEach() function. It works fine for me:

<Example render={ students =>

  Hi , {students.map( student => {return {student}}) }

} />